# is there are any alpha logic define in informix DB

Tags: informix, alpha

i am using informix DB , i need to get records that contain alpha [A-Za-z] character on last character 
what i try is :

```
select * from table_name 
where (SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='0' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='1' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='2' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='3' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='4' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='5' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='6' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='7' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='8' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='9') or (SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)=' ') or (SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)='') or (customer IS NULL)
```

is there are any way to write **where SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)=alpha** rather than write 
**SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='0' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='1' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='2' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='3' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='4' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='5' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='6' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='7' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='8' and SUBSTR(trim(customer),-1,1)!='9'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a 'recent' version of Informix (anything over 12.10 should do) you can use regex_match():

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.dbext.doc/ids_dbxt_544.htm

Something like :

```
> select * from table(set{'test','test1','tesT'})
  where regex_match(unnamed_col_1, '[a-zA-Z]$');

unnamed_col_1

test
tesT

2 row(s) retrieved.

>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Informix MATCHES operator, that is supported in any version.
The query would be like this:

```
select * from table_name 
 where customer matches "*[A-Za-z]"
```